# Ошибка Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function как убрать

Tags: javascript

У меня в системе есть живой поиск, работает хорошо меня устраивает, но в консоли постоянно ошибка показывается Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

Она никак не влияет на работу скрипта, но бесит что она просто есть...

Код поиска:

```
var suggest_count = 0;
var input_initial_value = '';
var suggest_selected = 0;

$(window).load(function(){
    // читаем ввод с клавиатуры
    $("#search_box").keyup(function(I){
        // определяем какие действия нужно делать при нажатии на клавиатуру
        switch(I.keyCode) {
            // игнорируем нажатия на эти клавишы
            case 13:  // enter
            case 27:  // escape
            case 38:  // стрелка вверх
            case 40:  // стрелка вниз
            break;

            default:
                // производим поиск только при вводе более 2х символов
                if($(this).val().length>2){ 

                    input_initial_value = $(this).val();
                    var id_cabinet = $(this).data("id_cabinet");
                    // производим AJAX запрос к /ajax/ajax.php, передаем ему GET query, в который мы помещаем наш запрос
                    $.get("/ajax_search.php?id_cabinet="+id_cabinet+"", { "search":$(this).val() },function(data){
                        //php скрипт возвращает нам строку, ее надо распарсить в массив.
                        // возвращаемые данные: ['test','test 1','test 2','test 3']
                        var list = eval("("+data+")"); 
                        suggest_count = list.length;
                        if(suggest_count > 0){
                            // перед показом слоя подсказки, его обнуляем
                            $("#search_advice_wrapper").html("").show();
                            for(var i in list){
                                if(list[i] != ''){
                                    // добавляем слою позиции
                                    $('#search_advice_wrapper').append('<div class="advice_variant">'+list[i]+'</div>');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, 'html');
                }
            break;
        }
    });

    // делаем обработку клика по подсказке
    $('.advice_variant').live('click',function(){
        // ставим текст в input поиска
        $('#search_box').val($(this).text());
        // прячем слой подсказки
        $('#search_advice_wrapper').fadeOut(350).html('');
    });

    // если кликаем на поле input и есть пункты подсказки, то показываем скрытый слой
    $('#search_box').click(function(event){
        //alert(suggest_count);
        if(suggest_count)
            $('#search_advice_wrapper').show();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

});


// если кликаем в любом месте сайта, нужно спрятать подсказку
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#search_advice_wrapper");
    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0){
        container.hide();
    }
});

function key_activate(n){
    $('#search_advice_wrapper div').eq(suggest_selected-1).removeClass('active');

    if(n == 1 && suggest_selected < suggest_count){
        suggest_selected++;
    }else if(n == -1 && suggest_selected > 0){
        suggest_selected--;
    }

    if( suggest_selected > 0){
        $('#search_advice_wrapper div').eq(suggest_selected-1).addClass('active');
        $("#search_box").val( $('#search_advice_wrapper div').eq(suggest_selected-1).text() );
    } else {
        $("#search_box").val( input_initial_value );
    }
}
```

Comment: Версия `jquery` у вас какая? А то `live` давно заменили на `on` ... `Deprecated 1.7`

Comment: Пробовали вместо `$(window).load(...)` поставить `ready(...)`?

Comment: спасибо поправил, теперь нет ошибки. не подумал про on =)